# The number of bits per symbol is less than one

Tags: digital-communications, bandwidth

For a channel of bandwidth B Hz and signal-to-noise ratio of S/N, i have used Shannon-formula to calculate the maximum channel capacity C. For transmitting at the nyquist baud rate (2 symbol/sec), when i substituded in nyquist formula to find the number of levels, and used the number of levels to find the number of bits per symbol, i found that the number of bits/symbol equals 0.5.
What does this mean?  How can this be achieved?

Comment: this mean *in average*, one symbol convoys 0.5 bits. For example 2 symbols are needed to send out 1 bit.

Comment: @ Alex TP The number of bits per symbol is log-2(M), and M equals 2,4,8,16,...                        None of these values yield 0.5.

Comment: $\log_2(M)$ is the number of bits sent out per symbol, not the number of bits per symbol that guarantees arbitrary low codeword error probabilities assuming codeword length approachs infinity.